# Repeated nodes in tree-decomposition of a graph is allowed or not?

Tags: graph-theory

As we know, a [*tree-decomposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_decomposition) of a graph must have following features:

1. All vertices are covered
2. All edges are covered
3. The connectivity condition

I think using repeated nodes in *tree-decomposition* must be allowed by definition. Is it true?

Comment: i was going to add this in my answer, but its not relevant. Why are we allowed $X_i$ to contain vertices $u,v$ such that $u$ and $v$ do not share an edge?

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry, In my question, you can assume for each $u,v\in X_i$ they share an edge. but $X_i$ is a copy of another node in tree-decomposition.

Comment: i kept on finding references to the single node diagram, which contradicts this idea generally, except for $K_n$

Comment: @JonMarkPerry re why non-adjacent vertices are allowed to be in the same bag: because otherwise you would only be able to decompose chordal graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic definition of tree decompositioning allows it. If we are trying to minimize the graph diameter or node count, then obviously they are redundant, and for algorithmic calculations they can be eliminated.

From the Wikipedia definition in your link is the definition of **smooth**:

> A tree decomposition $(X, T = (I, F))$ of treewidth $k$ is smooth, if:
>
> - $\forall i \in I : |X_i| = k + 1$,
> - $\forall (i, j) \in F : |X_i \cap X_j| = k$

This disallows repeated nodes, as $|X_i \cap X_j| = k+1$ if $X_i=X_j$.